# Change color of text from an array dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using Jquery to do some things from a website that I'm working on; I'm doing some requests and from the data that I get there are some values with color names and I'm storing them in an array; what I want to do is change the color of each one because sometimes there are different colors on each requests.

I.E. User does request; from the data there is a  Green and Red value, before sending them to the page I want to change the color of Green to Green and Red to Red. If another request is made and the colors this time are Blue and Yellow I'd like to change the colors again with the process from above.

This is what I have:

```
var typeArr = [];
for (let l in data.types) {
        typeArr.unshift(data.types[l].type.name); //data.types is the data from the request
    }

//This is the appended info at the page
$('#types').html(`${typeArr[0].capitalizeFirstLetter()}`);
if (typeArr[1] !== undefined)
{
    $('#types').append(`/${typeArr[1].capitalizeFirstLetter()}`);
}
```

I'm not exactly experiencing an error; I just want to know how to do that. That's what I have and it shows the names in the correct order but I want to change the color of the words. There are max 2 words in the array per request.

Comment: show what you have done..show code where you are facing problem.

Comment: `$(selector).css('background-color', 'red');`

Comment: Alright; I edited it. and @CircleHsiao, yes, I know about that but the thing is that I want to change the exact word if it is in the array. Like, see if the word is in the array, if it is in the array, change the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to decorate each word with its color, you'll need to wrap it in an html tag, in this case, I used `<span></span>` for the example.

```js
$("#testme").click(function (){
    var arr = [ "Red", "Blue"];
    var selectedWord = "Red";

    if( $.inArray(arr, selectedWord) ){
       var newtext = $("<span>"+selectedWord+"</span>").css("color", selectedWord.toLowerCase());
       $("#myDiv").append(newtext);

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv">Text will appear here.</div>
<button id="testme">Test me!</button>
```

Comment: This was it, did some tweaking and got it working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Still not really sure what you are looking for.
However, according to your comment

> see if the word is in the array, if it is in the array, change the color

So is this what you need? [ref](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

```
jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex ] )
```

Usage for example

```
<div id="myDiv">something</div>
```

& jquery

```
var arr = [ "Red", "Blue"];
if(jQuery.inArray("Blue", arr)>0){
   $("#myDiv").css('background-color', 'blue');
}
```

Comment: Hmm, not exactly. I'm sorry that I didn't explain my issue more in depth. I'll try to explain in here again. I do a request, the request sends back data and I store part of that data which are the colors to an array. Now they are in that array and I want to change the colors of the TEXT of each word. If from the data I got Red and Green as colors in the HTML I want to put a Red word with red color and a Green word with green color. Only the text of each one. Colors can change on each request but I take care of that. In the HTML they're printed like "Green/Red" in a space which isn't important.